# How can I get the timestamp for tomorrow 00h10?

Tags: php, date, time

To prevent misunderstandings: All my code lines where fine, and they work correctly. I just had a wrong parameter in my `date()`, where I displayed the seconds `date('H:s')`, where it should've displayed the minutes as `date('H:i')`. (Thanks to [chumkiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1049668/chumkiu) for the hint.)

---

I want to fetch the timestamp for the upcoming day at 00h10.

I thought I could use the `strtotime()` function, e.g. like

```
$timestamp = strtotime('tomorrow 00:10');
```

But when I check

```
$mydate = date('Y-m-d H:s', $timestamp);
var_dump($mydate);
```

the output is

```
string(16) "2013-10-03 00:00"
```

The documentation of `strtotime()` has a lot of examples how to get different times

```
echo strtotime("now"), "\n";
echo strtotime("10 September 2000"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 day"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week"), "\n";
echo strtotime("+1 week 2 days 4 hours 2 seconds"), "\n";
echo strtotime("next Thursday"), "\n";
echo strtotime("last Monday"), "\n";
```

But none of them comes close to my problem.

Funny enough: I can do this

```
$time_h = strtotime('tomorrow +10 hours');
$time_m = strtotime('tomorrow +10 minutes');
```

whereas `$time_h` returns the wanted result (`10:00`), but `$time_m` does not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean `H:i` and not `H:s`?

Comment: Dude, that was exactly my error! The values were correct, I just didn't debug correctly...

Comment: what chumkiu says: 's' is seconds, 'i' is minutes, so your `mydate` doesn't print your minutes

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Emberassing...

Comment: Someone feel free to formulate this as an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply

```
echo date("Y-m-d 00:10",strtotime('tomorrow'))
```

However in your code the error is the use of `H:s` instead of `H:i`

From [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> **i**: Minutes with leading zeros |    00 to 59
>
> **s**: Seconds, with leading zeros |   00 through 59

Comment: Yeah, also does the job. But my problem was somewhere else. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 9):

just add 10 minutes:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('tomorrow +10min');
```